# Why does use of delete cause core dump?

Tags: c++

I'm currently teaching myself C++ using Kubuntu 19.04 Kate 18.12.3 and g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0

In Kate's Tools/Mode/sources menu I select either C++ or ISO C++.

I've coded up a small program the object of which was to fix a deliberate memory leak presented in the previous exercise. Here is my code.

```
/* Fix the program from Exercise 6. */

#include <iostream>

int myFunction(int * pInt);

int main()
{
    int myVar;
    int * pInt = new int;
    pInt = &myVar;
    *pInt = myFunction(&myVar);
    std::cout << "The value of myVar is " << *pInt << std::endl;
    delete pInt;   // Free up pointer.
    pInt = 0;      // Make pointer safe.
    return 0;
}

int myFunction(int * pInt)
{
    *pInt = 2;
    return *pInt;
}
```

When I pass this code through g++ the following output is generated.

The value of myVar is 2
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

However, when the delete instruction is commented out, the following output is generated.

The value of myVar is 2

Given that delete is a standard keyword in C++, why should its use in this code cause a core dump ?

I am at a loss to understand this and would really appreciate any help that can be given.

Best regards,

Stuart

Comment: Just because something is a "standard keyword" does not guarantee that there is no way to use it incorrectly. And when you use anything, not just `delete`, incorrectly, [demons will fly out of your nose and will likely cause a core dump](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Doesn't have to be `delete`. It can be anything. Even a `for` loop can cause a core dump. Welcome to C++, the most complicated and difficult general purpose programming language in use today.

Comment: *"Given that delete is a standard keyword in C++, why should its use in this code cause a core dump?"*... Oh boy. Even though C++ makes it easier to write code which makes it harder to do accidents, you also have all the power of C to shoot yourself in the foot: the revolver is loaded, cocked and strapped to your belt so it may be difficult to even remove it without it accidentally going off.

Comment: Why are you doing `pInt = &myVar;`?

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the feedback/explanation and welcome. ;-)

Comment: @hyde: So I have just learned. :-(   Still, I do like a challenge. ;-)

Comment: @Eljay: I wanted pInt to point to the location used by myVar and then use pInt to manipulate the contents of myVar. It can be clearly seen that I had not clearly understood the operation of "new". Hindsight reveals that I could have used "int * pInt = &myVar" to initialize the pointer. Through experimentation I have found out that, near the end of the program, if I first set the pointer to zero and then(!) delete it then the program runs cleanly and does not abort and create a core dump. I used these two operations in the order that I did because that was how they were ordered in the textbook.

Comment: @Stuart Modern C++ is actually very safe, as long as you follow a set of rules. One of the rules is, you very rarely call `new` yourself (and you have to be able to explain why),  and you basically never call `delete` yourself. Instead you use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` when you have to go that low level, and mostly use higher level containers like `std::vector`. Also, when you use a naked pointer anywhere at all, you should be able to explain why (instead of a value or a reference or a smart pointer).

Comment: @hyde: Thank you for another informative response. Please remember that I am at an early stage of familiarizing myself with C++.  From what (little) I know of C++, I seem to remember that vectors were part of the STL. I am still at an elementary level and so have yet to take any kind of look at STL. I have never heard/read of std::unique_ptr and so don't know how to use it. When I have finished working through my current text book I will start on Stack Overflow's "C Plus Plus Notes for Professionals" of which I already have the pdf.

Answer (score 7):

In this statement

```
pInt = &myVar;
```

you have overwritten the previous value returned by `new int` and replaced it with a pointer to a local variable. That's why `delete` crashes (technically, it's [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) because [operator `delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) can't free local variables and can only free what's allocated with respective `new` operator.

When you have reassigned the pointer, you lost access to the one returned by `new`. This is a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: This wording is slightly confusing. This implies that `delete` is crashing because of a memory leak.

Comment: Point taken. Better now?

Comment: The "this is a memory leak" should be at the end of the answer imo, its not the main problem at hand and should be addressed last "btw by doing this you also leak the newed int" or something along those lines.

Comment: @usr: Thank you for your explanation. It does make things a bit clearer. Please also see my response to Eljay above about why I ordered certain operations as shown in my original code. I have also learned that deleting a null pointer is guaranteed to be safe. This explains my re-ordering of the "delete" and "nullifying of the pointer" operations in the amended code (not shown).

Comment: @Stuart Indeed that 'I could have used "int * pInt = &myVar" to initialize the pointer.' is correct. If it helps I may add: a pointer is simply pointer to some object. With `int *p = new int;` - you are saying "point to some int that's freshly allocated on heap". With `int *p = &myVar;` you are saying "there's an `int` variable `myVar` and I simply want to refer/access it though `p`". In both cases the memory for the pointer `p` itself is allocated on stack (automatic storage).

Comment: @Borgleader: Thank you for your response. It has helped to further clarify my coding error.

Comment: @usr: Thank you for such a swift(!!) and further clarifying response. It is much appreciated, as are all the responses.